# Pyomo breaks when solving iteratively

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, pyomo

I am doing a loop across year, and for each year I solve an optimization problem. Inside the loop I do:

```
        #Optimization
        opt = SolverFactory("ipopt")
        results = opt.solve(model3 , keepfiles=False, load_solutions=False)
        model3.solutions.load_from(results)
```

The program works well, but I am having some times (randomly) this problem:

File "", line 47, in 
    results = opt.solve(model3 , keepfiles=False, load_solutions=False)

File "C:\Users\escriva\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 631, in solve
    result = self._postsolve()

File "C:\Users\escriva\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 282, in _postsolve
    os.remove(self._soln_file)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\escriva\tmpc2aly83o.pyomo.sol'

Then, I run it again and it works, but it breaks again (randomly) several years later. I think that it's related to the next iteration of the optimization having problems because the past optimization is not totally cleared up.

Any help?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think that I solved my question:

- I was working on my Dropbox directory an someone told me that this might be the cause of the slow response when deleting solver files.

So I moved my directory to my C drive and now I don't have any problem.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I encountered the same problem with Onedrive. It seems like using clouds is in some cases, not a good idea.